# restangular get full json response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

I'm new to restangular and trying to integrate it in my app. Here is what i done so far:

```
 MyResource.getList(params).then((dt) ->
      console.log dt
    )
```

If I use `$http.get` then I get my full json object

```
{
 "param" : "a",
 "param2" : "b",
 "data": [
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "v1",
    "address": "some long address"
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "vadsf",
    "address": "some long address again"
  },
  {
    "id": 13,
    "name": "asdf",
    "address": "another long address"
  }
 ]
}
```

but with restangular, I'm getting following:

```
[
 {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "v1",
    "address": "some long address"
 },
 {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "vadsf",
    "address": "some long address again"
 },
 {
    "id": 13,
    "name": "asdf",
    "address": "another long address"
 }
]
```

How I can get full json instead of only data array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted it out. In my app config

```
        RestangularProvider.addResponseInterceptor((data, operation) ->
            if operation is 'getList'
              extractedData = data.data
              if data.total then extractedData.param = data.param
              if data.total then extractedData.param2 = data.param2
              return extractedData
            else data
        )
```